# Am I solving this differential equation correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been tasked with solving the following differential equation:

$$y'(t)+7\sin(t)y(t)=(te^{\cos(t)})^7$$

I recognize (I think?) that this is an equation of the type:

$$y'(t)+p(t)y(t)=q(t)$$

which has the solution:

$$y(t)=e^{-P(t)}\int e^{P(t)}q(t)dt$$

However, I just can't figure out which
 function goes where in the solutioon formula. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you see why $p(t) = 7\sin(t)$ and why $q(t) = (te^{\cos(t)})^{7}$?

Comment: Yes, you are doing it right. Now proceed.

Comment: So the correct solution is $y(t)=e^{7cos(t)}\int e^{-7cos(t)}(te^{cos(t)})^{7}dt$ ?

Comment: Isn't it  $y(t)=e^{-7cos(t)}\int e^{7cos(t)}(te^{cos(t)})^{7}dt?$  You seem to have changed the sign of $p$.  By the way, if you differentiate the formula, you'll see why it gives the solution.

Comment: Start by writing down $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define

$z(t):=(e^{-cos(t)})^7y(t)$

and you can observe that $z(t)$ verify the equality

$z’(t)=t^7$